# Jquery copying the attribute of the the thead tr td to the tbody tr td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can we copy the data from thead to tbody? I only wanted to get the data-date

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2017-10-08"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-09"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-10"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-11"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-12"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Can i copy the attribute of the thead tr td? to the tbody tr td? so it will also become

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2017-10-08"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-09"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-10"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-11"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-12"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2017-10-08"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-09"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-10"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-11"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-12"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Note that I cant manully put the attribute coz this is coming from a plugin

Comment: Will you have only one row in the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set header `td` value in an array then set it using that arraywith jQuery `each()` function. check updated snippet below..

```js
var xyz = [];
$('table thead td').each(function(){
    xyz.push($(this).data('date'));
})
$('table tbody td').each(function(i,el){
    $(this).data('date', xyz[i]).html(xyz[i]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' celpadding="2">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2017-10-08"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-09"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-10"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-11"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-12"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. Get both `tds` and iterate over one, use that index and copy the `data-date` into the `tbody` `tds`.

```js
const theadTds = $('thead tr td');
const tbodyTds = $('tbody tr td');

theadTds.each((index, td) => { 
    const tbodyTd = tbodyTds.eq(index); // Get current tbody td
    tbodyTd.data('date', $(td).data('date')); // Set the `data-date` to the `thead td` `data-date`
    console.log(tbodyTd.data('date'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td data-date="2017-10-08"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-09"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-10"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-11"></td>
   <td data-date="2017-10-12"></td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: I like your answer but unfortunately it's not browser compatible.

Comment: In which case is my answer differs from yours?

Comment: Ah, you about arrow function. Just change it into the function. But I think every front end code must be transpiled before the production

Comment: Yes i agree with you, but it should be proper explained to OP :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for any interim variables etc. Just iterate over the columns, this does ALL rows in body, if you just want first one you can do that also.

```
$('thead').find('tr').find('td').each(function(index){ 
   $('tbody').find('tr').find('td').eq(index).data('date',$(this).data('date')):
});
```

Only first row in body

```
$('thead').find('tr').find('td').each(function(index){ 
   $('tbody').find('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).data('date',$(this).data('date')):
});
```

Alternate syntax if that is more clear to you

```
$('thead').find('tr').find('td').each(function(index,element){ 
   $('tbody').find('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).data('date',$(element).data('date')):
});
```